# Rewrite statement to use loc

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am brand new to Pandas and following along with a Plurasight course I have gotten stuck on how can I rewrite the following to use loc instead of chained indexing.

```
every_6th_row = pd.Series(range(5, len(df),6))

# can you rewrite this line to use df.loc
df['MIN_TEMP_GROUND'].drop(every_6th_row).isnull().all()
```

Within the dataframe there is only a value in the column MIN_TEMP_GROUND every six rows, so this statement checks to ensure that all the other rows are null.

I have tried a number of combinations such as:

```
df.drop(df.loc[every_6th_row, 'MIN_TEMP_GROUND'])
```

without success. Any pointers to where I am going wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a 0 indexed DataFrame, let's try using the modulus of the index and keep all rows except the 6th:

```
df.loc[(df.index % 6) != 5, 'MIN_TEMP_GROUND'].isnull().all()  # True
```

---

Or more generally based on the `shape` of the DataFrame and `arange` if the index is not a 0 indexed range already:

```
df.loc[(np.arange(df.shape[0]) % 6) != 5, 'MIN_TEMP_GROUND'].isnull().all()
```

---

Sample Data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'MIN_TEMP_GROUND': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
                                       np.nan, np.nan, 5] * 2})
```

```
    MIN_TEMP_GROUND
0               NaN
1               NaN
2               NaN
3               NaN
4               NaN
5               5.0
6               NaN
7               NaN
8               NaN
9               NaN
10              NaN
11              5.0
```

```
df.loc[(df.index % 6) != 5, 'MIN_TEMP_GROUND']
```

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
6    NaN
7    NaN
8    NaN
9    NaN
10   NaN
Name: MIN_TEMP_GROUND, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Perfect - First answer fits the spec because the course hasn't yet touched on shape